# Python struct.unpack format from header .h file

Tags: python, struct, marshalling

I have a header (.h) file describing some datastructures (the data is collected from a sensor). Example:

```
...
struct SensorIf
{
    DWORD       SensorType;                     
    char        Name[StrSize];    
    DWORD       SerialNumber;     
    ...
};
...
```

I also have measurements stored as binary files, containing something like this:

```
0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x...
```

As far as I understand, binary data can be parsed using the header file.
Can I do that in python?
If no, what is the easiest way to do it?
I figured out that probably `unpack` function from `struct` package is what I need, but how do I create a format string from header (.h) file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is to use ctypes bult-in library.
One has to manually specify all the structures and unions in ctypes subclasses and than parse the file with something like:

```py
from ctypes import Structure, c_uint

class MyStructure(Structure):
   _fields_ = [
        ("field1", c_uint)
    ]


with open('binaryfile', 'rb') as f:
    data = MyStructure()
    f.readinto(data)
    print(data.field1)
```